# C# Splash screen with just an animated GIF in a picture box crashes the picture box randomly

Tags: c#, .net, image, gif, splash-screen

I put a very simple Splash screen for my Windows forms app, with just a PictureBox. The form's transparency key and background color are set to be the same. I set the image of the picture box to be an animated gif file. It worked fine on one of my machines.

On some machines, after about a second of animation, I get the error image with a red X on the picture box, at completely random instants. Once I get the error, the same red X appears over buttons at random.

The compiled and built exe file when run, throws a JIT Compilation error message, even the buttons of the error dialog box turn to a red X. Here are the error details..

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

(I am not pasting the code here, because it's so simple and stupid)

> ******* *Exception Text* ********* System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A
>   generic error occurred in GDI+.    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension dimension, Int32
>   frameIndex)    at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.ImageInfo.UpdateFrame()
>   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e,
>   Int16 layer)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ******* *Loaded Assemblies* ********* mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- ERingWizzard
>       Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///B:/BuildersAvenue/Wizzard/ERingWizzard/ERingWizzard/bin/Debug/ERingWizzard.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>
> ******* *JIT Debugging* ********* To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
>   with debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

Is there a work around this or is that a stupid question to ask? I googled and looked around, none of the people who had this problem had a proper solution :(

Additional info: The gif image is non-rectangular and that was why, I needed to use the Transparent key of the form set to be the same as its background..

Here is the code..

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.Hide();

        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashScreen));

        t.Start();

        InitializeComponent();

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        ticker.Interval = 1800000;
        ticker.Start();

        t.Abort();

        this.Show();
        this.ResumeLayout();
    }

    private void SplashScreen()
    {
        Application.Run(new Splash());
    }
```

Comment: Is there any multithreading happening around here?

Comment: I run the Splash screen in a new thread Matt..

Comment: Anyway, I don't have the time to fix an ideal work around for this.. but I fixed it. I placed the picture box inside a panel. I ran the exe file for about 20 times now without encountering the great red X (of dot-f-net).

Comment: Ah well, glad to hear you got it fixed!